# Use HTML for arduino in a raspberry with Python3

Tags: html, arduino, raspberry-pi, nodemcu

Good morning,
I currently have an html page with graphs, gauge and various read values created and published by an arduino in C ++.
I would like to pass everything on a raspberry in python3.
Is it possible to keep the html file and integrate it or use it as it is?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you probably want to read sensor values with Raspberry Pi (or anything similar) and display that data through the web app. You have an existing HTML template that integrates with Arduino C++ logic and now you want to move it to Python. If that's the case, you can use the Python-based web framework like Flask and adapt it with slight changes. If you know Python, you can learn the basics of Flask in a few days and successfully use it with your project.